# publishing a windows form application - error with the references

Tags: c#, publishing, windows-forms-designer

is there a way to publish a windows form application in c# that can include all the dll references as well as all the data-sets in one file??

every time i try to publish the application, i get a message displaying:

> Exception: missing reference

any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: Go to the reference properties and set Copy Local to True?

Comment: Do you use the `System.Reflection` namespace in your application?

Comment: no i do not use the reflections

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) for merging the assemblies:

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a
>   single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes
>   with several options for controlling the processing and format of the
>   output.

I guess that the data-sets you refer to are actually strongly typed `System.Data.DataSet` classes. They will probably be compiled and included in the assemblies they belong to.

Comment: This can be set up to run automatically when msbuild compiles. Excellent tool.  Another option is to invest in an obfuscation program, they will also merge assemblies.